# What are these marks on pepper leaves?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, plant-health, indoors, diseases

My wife and I have noticed this on some leaves. Her plants had ~30 leaves like this, and mine had one that showed up yesterday (I think I'm gonna clip that leaf just in case).

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

These pictures above are all from her plant. The marks on my leaf (which I can get a pic of later) looked like the the same pattern of a caterpillar eating it. I know it's not, but is it maybe a venom or infection from an insect? Or more likely bacterial/fungal/viral or nutrient related (deficiency/over-surplus)?

If these are "leaf miners," how do we go about getting rid of them and preventing them further? Neem Oil?

Both plants are peppers on a balcony in  Southern California. Wife's plant is a Pequin variety and mine is a Trinidad Scorpion.

What other data would be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You've got leaf miners, a bit of fungus.  Totally normal.  Go ahead and clip off those leaves.  Leaf miners were a fly awhile back that planted its eggs i the leaf and those tunnels in the epidermis are where the larvae have been eating.

I am assuming these are peppers, yes?  Is this indoors or out of doors?  Is this on your balcony?  They should not have any problems.  Those leaf miners and bit of fungus will not stop your plants from making seed...peppers?

Give us more information to help more fully?